# How to delete some of the form data in Firefox

Tags: firefox, forms

I want to delete some form data in Firefox. At `Tools > Clear Recent History...` there is option to delete all form data, but I do not want to do that. I expected that highlighting the entry I want deleted and pressing delete button would delete the it, but that does not work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To delete saved form data in Firefox on a item-by-item basis:

- Highlight what you want to be deleted in the drop-down.
- Make certain that the drop-down remains on the screen.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove that entry.

Note: If you click an item from the drop-down, it populates the input box and the drop-down disappears.  If you highlight the text in the input box and press shift+delete, the only result is that the input box is cleared.  Doing this does not delete the saved form data.

Comment: This still works (as of 2019). To be clear about the process: On the webpage with the form, first clear the form field. Then you can open said drop-down by clicking again into the form field.

Comment: This still works as of 2022. To highlight an element of the drop-down you have to press the DOWN arrow. If you mouse over the element, it won't work.

Comment: due to a pw management plugin it worked for me ONLY using the up arrow.

Comment: Works as of March, 2024 in FF 123.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the entry to be deleted and press shift+delete.

Source: http://www.missiondata.com/blog/uncategorized/53/firefox-saved-form-data-frustrations/

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: *No longer true with the new Webextension API. Form History control manages a separate history.*

---

Use the "Form History Control" extension. Can automatically cleanup just the unwanted formdata.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox Mobile you can, when the the dropdown appears you can sleect-and-hold-and-swipe-left.

[image: Select-and-hold]

[image: Swipe left]